# Problems with getting Tables from Databases using sqlsrv_query in php

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I am having problems with `sqlsrv_query` in PHP. I get the following warning:

```
Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Status.php on line 76

Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Status.php on line 76
A error occured: Array
```

This is my code:

```
<?php
    
$conn = OpenConnectionMsSQL();
#var_dump($conn);
$sql_select = "Select state_desc from sys.databases";
$params = array();

$query = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql_select, $params) or die('A error occured:' . sqlsrv_errors());

$res = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);
while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_assoc($res))
{ echo ($row['state_desc']); }

?>
```

and this is my connection code:

```
<?php
    function OpenConnectionMsSQL()
    {
        try{
            $serverName = "***";
            $database = "***";
            $uid = "***";
            $pwd = "***";
            
            $connectionOptions = array("Database"=>"$database","Uid"=>"$uid","PWD"=>"$pwd");
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);
            if($conn == false)
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
            }
        
        catch(Exception $e)
            {
                exit("<h1>"."Verbindung fehlgeschlagen!". "</br>". "Server Stopped"."</h1>");#.$e->getMessage());
                exit("<!--"."<h1>"."Serverstatus: Verbindung fehlgeschlagen!". "</br>". "Server Stopped"."</h1>"."-->");#.$e->getMessage();
            
            }
    }

?>
```

How do I fetch my results correctly?

Comment: A) PDO is a lot better than smashing around with the low level SQL Server driver functions. B) You're probably getting an error but not recognizing it. PDO can raise exceptions which means you don't have to explicitly test the success or failure of each call.

Comment: I have also tried it with PDOs but its the same result

Comment: The "Array to string conversion..." error is coming from the `sqlsrv_errors()`. This function returns an array, you should be using `print_r` or `var_dump`. Fixing this will at least give you a more meaningful reason as to why your query is failing.

Answer (score 0):

I just forgot to use `sql_fetch_array`, so I couldn't fetch my results.

The following snippet fixes the problem

```
$sql_select = "Select state_desc,name from sys.databases where name='master'";
$sql_version = "Select @@version as Version";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql_select) or die('A error occured: ' . print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
$version = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql_version) or die('A error occured: ' . print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

if (sqlsrv_has_rows($version)) {
    $data2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $version, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    echo "Serverinfo: ".$data2['Version']."<br/>"."<br/>";
} else {
    echo "No data found";
}
```